# transmission ports still open after transmission "failed"

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, transmission

I am currently trying to get transmission to work on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 server. It's a torrent downloader, that can be controlled using the web interface and the command line. I have started it before successfully but it needed to be restarted. Now when I tried to restart it, it started but it was never able to bind to any of the ports it wants, namely 9091 and 51413. After running `sudo netstat -tulpn` I got these relevant lines as a response:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp       27      0 0.0.0.0:9091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp      129      0 0.0.0.0:51413           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::51413                :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp   426240      0 0.0.0.0:51413           0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

After running `sudo netstat -antlp` I found out there are A LOT of connections still on `CLOSE_WAIT` as well as on `SYN_RECV`. I don't exactly know how to deal with this. The error I now get when trying to start Transmission is as follows:

```
[2020-06-22 20:10:04.469] RPC Server Unable to bind to 0.0.0.0:9091, retrying in 5 seconds (rpc-server.c:822)
[2020-06-22 20:26:00.690] Couldn't bind port 51413 on 0.0.0.0: Address already in use (Is another copy of Transmission already running?) (net.c:452)
[2020-06-22 20:26:00.690] Couldn't bind port 51413 on ::: Address already in use (Is another copy of Transmission already running?) (net.c:452)
```

And similar errors. Not being able to bind to the port, as it's already in use is the main issue here. Transmission is not already running in the background, as `htop` shows no activity, and neither does `service --status-all`, which shows transmission-daemon as turned off.

Does anyone know exactly how to deal with this? (preferably without a reboot)

Comment: Have you checked for another transmission process?

Comment: Yes i have, there is none. And besides, I figure it would show up under PID/Program using ```sudo netstat -tulpn```, because other PIDs show up for other processes